# Reduce memory footprint of android services of full blown applications

Tags: android, memory

I have an app that uses a remote service (a class that extends Service and uses the  android:process=":remote" - flag) to check for updates regularily, even when the app itself is force quitted. However, even though this service consists only of one .java Service class, it still consumes more than 20 MB of memory.

I guess the problem is that the service uses the same package as my main program, so whenever the service is spawned, it also loads all the bitmaps, libraries and resources in the background (which it will never need). Is there a way to produce really small services with less than 1 MB of footprint using the same APK as the main app? (P.S. using Android Studio)